# xcode: blank screen when running with iPad simulator with storyboards

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, storyboard

Seems like a basic question but I just can't figure it out:

xcode 5.0 iOS app. Eventually I'll have an iPad-specific storyboard but for now I just want to use the iPhone storyboard on all devices. The simulator runs fine when set to "iPhone 5.0 simulator" but when run as "iPad 5.0 simulator" it just shows a blank white screen.

I have files called MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard and MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard. The iPad storyboard contains nothing specific because I've been working only on the iPhone storyboard. (This of course is why I get the blank screen when running the iPad simulator.) However, I can't seem to find a way to "disable" the iPad storyboard and have it use the iPhone storyboard when running the iPad simulator.

I've tried removing the file (results in compile error) and soft linking the iPhone storyboard to the iPad one (results in an internal error).

Under the project "Summary" I have "Devices" set to "iPhone".

Under my "Build Settings" I have "Targeted Device Family" set to "iPhone".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

under the Project settings change the target of the MainStoryboard from MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard to MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard